# Get a trial version of VB 6.0

Tags: visual-basic

I have an old VB 6.0 file that I need to open.  I can't open it with VB.NET, so I was wondering if there was anywhere to get a trial version of 6.0

Answer (score 3):

[Have a look at Microsoft's Resource Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788229)

You can always upgrade VB6 projects to later versions of Visual Studio using the upgrade wizard.

Visual Basic 6 itself has been discontinued long ago, so unless you can find a second hand CD to install it from, you're out of luck.

Comment: Just about the only way to get VB6 these days is with an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to open it with Visual Basic for Applications.

Comment: Can I use VBA to produce a dll?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no.